# How can I display a rendered object inside a different class layout?

Tags: java, android

Okay, so I'm using Rajawali (See: http://www.rozengain.com/blog/2011/08/23/announcing-rajawali-an-opengl-es-2-0-based-3d-framework-for-android/) to create a 3D sphere with an image of the Earth on it.

I already have the sphere successfully created but now I'm starting to add UI elements around the rotating sphere. Up top, I have a header image and my end goal is to add a click event to the image and have it load up a menu on click. However, I think the reason why my onclick event isn't working is because Rajawali doesn't support touch events yet.

So, now what I'm looking into is somehow creating a normal xml layout with the header image and then *loading* the render of the 3D sphere into the middle of the layout. Is this possible? How?

If not, then I think I will look into using a different framework for my 3D sphere. Which one is the easiest or has a nice tutorial for a 3D sphere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Object picking has been added to Rajawali. See this tutorial for more info:

http://www.rozengain.com/blog/2012/03/23/rajawali-tutorial-12-object-picking/